# EJB: Why do I get this error in JNDI lookup?

Tags: java, ejb, jndi, lookup

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
StatelessInterogareRemote beanStatelessRemote = (StatelessInterogareRemote) ctx
    .lookup("java:global/ShopEAP/ShopEJB/StatelessInterogare!shop.StatelessInterogareRemote");
StatefulShopCartLocal beanStateful = (StatefulShopCartLocal) ctx
    .lookup("java:global/ShopEAP/ShopEJB/StatefulShopCart!shop.StatefulShopCartLocal");
```

When I run the application, the error appears after the second lookup:

```
[[[ Error ]]]: Lookup failed for 'java:global/ShopEAP/ShopEJB/StatelessInterogare' in SerialContext 
INFO: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@89708c
WARNING: "IOP00100006: (BAD_PARAM) Class com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate is not Serializable"
org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM:   vmcid: OMG  minor code: 6 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.OMGSystemException.notSerializable(OMGSystemException.java:990)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.OMGSystemException.notSerializable(OMGSystemException.java:1005)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.ORBUtility.throwNotSerializableForCorba(ORBUtility.java:753)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like either:

1. The class implementing `StatelessInterogareRemote` is not serializable or
2. Some method in the interface `StatelessInterogareRemote` has (recursively) a parameter or a return type which is not serializable

Just to be clear: a *serializable* object is one that implements the `Serializable` interface; and by *recursively* I mean to say that the object, its attributes, its attributes' attributes and so on - all they must be serializable, too.

Since you're indicating that the EJB is stateless, it should be clear that it must not have attributes, but just in case: all the attributes in the EJB must also be serializable, or transient in case they can't be serialized.

Comment: Seems that the serialization is the problem. There is a Statefull bean witn 2 attributes: private transient HashMap<Integer, Integer> qty; si private ArrayList<ProdusDTO> products; The class implements Serializable, but still not working.

Comment: Check if ProdusDTO is Serializable, and if its attributes are Serializable, and so on

Comment: @Oscar: WHy does the class implementing StatelessInterogareRemote a.k.a the EJB bean need to be serializable?

Comment: @Victor Objects in an EJB should be serializable in order to support session replication across several nodes in a cluster, as part of a high-availability strategy

Comment: Yes..that goes for the method args and return types...but hte bean itself need not be serializable i think

Comment: @Victor if the bean is not serializable, nothing inside of it will be able to be serialized. This is very important for stateful beans, in a clustered environment non-serializable stateful session ejbs don't make any sense

Comment: Thanks...but StatelessInterogareRemote seems stateless...so i was asking.